# Convert PowerPoint 2007/2010 file formats to svg using pptx4j in Java

Tags: java, svg, powerpoint

In my Java project I am working on PowerPoint 2007/2010 file format so I am Using pptx4j open source project.

However, I don't know how to convert PowerPoint 2007/2010 file formats to an SVG file.

Can anybody help me?