# How to show ppt in android using Apache POI?

Tags: android, powerpoint, apache-poi

I am trying to show the PPT files in android. I started with Apache POI, bcoz I haven't found any free open source jar. 
I starting with converting ppt slides to images referring this link [Export PowerPoint slides into java.awt.Graphics2D](http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/how-to-shapes.html#Render)

Now, this is in Java. I am unable to find Dimension, BufferedImage, Graphics2D classes. I have imported poi-scratchpad-3.8-20120326.jar in my build path settings. i think i am missing some other jars. 
Will any one point what other jars has to be included or is there any other way to get this done in android?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252626/convert-powerpoint-2007-2010-file-formats-to-svg-using-pptx4j-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can't find Graphics2D other class support because android does not support awt packages of java. you have to fetch all images using apache poi.